# Cannot send ETH to contract using solc 0.8.4 using truffle console (revert)

Tags: truffle, solc, web3js-v1.x

I spend like 6 to 8 hours on this issue, finally asking here on the following problem.

**Goal**

I want to sent ETH from one of the default Ganache addresses to the deployed contract *SportBet*.

**Versions**

```
Truffle v5.3.4 (core: 5.3.4)
Solidity - 0.8.4 (solc-js)
Node v15.9.0
Web3.js v1.3.5
Ganache v2.5.4
```

**Using**

```
macOS 11.2.3
vsCode 1.56.1
```

**Contract**

```
contract SportBet {

string public name = "SportBet";
address public owner;

event Received(address, uint256);

receive() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

fallback() external payable {}
}
```

Then on truffle console declaring

```
sportBet = await SportBet.deployed()
```

Now sending ETH using web3

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sportBet.address, from:accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei('1'), gas: 100000})
```

Always ending with

```
Uncaught Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

**Get gas price**

```
web3.eth.getGasPrice()
```

**Result**

```
'20000000000'
```

**Update**

When I run on truffle console

```
migrate --reset
```

I get

```
2_deploy_contracts.js
```

=====================

### Replacing 'SportBet'

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

```
"SportBet" -- Provided address g is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does console.log(sportBet.address) and console.log(account[0]) give u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to an error with your migration file.

Be sure to have a migration file in the `migrations` folder. You can name it `2_deploy_contract.js` :

```
const SportBet = artifacts.require("SportBet");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(SportBet);
};
```

The `truffle-config.js` file at the root of your project should look something like this :

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
      development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.8.4",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  }
};
```

Then you should be good with the following procedure :

1. Open the truffle development console using the `truffle develop` command line.
2. Deploy the smart contract with `truffle migrate --reset`.
3. Get the contract instance :

`sportBet = await SportBet.deployed()`

4. Send the ETH to the contract to trigger the `receive` function :

   `web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sportBet.address, from:accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei('1'), gas: 100000})`
5. Check the ETH balance of the smart contract :

   `web3.eth.getBalance(sportBet.address)`

It returns `'1000000000000000000'` as expected.

Comment: @frankfurt-laravel You’re welcome ! In this case, you can mark the answer as accepted (by clicking on the « V »).